# Broadcast fragment-shader output to all FBO color attachments?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glfw, opengl-es-3.0

Is there some way to get OpenGL ES 3.0 to broadcast the value of a single-output fragment shader to all active (as per `glDrawBuffers()`) FBO color attachments?

If possible I'd like to keep my shaders more-or-less as-is and avoid the re-write required by multiple `layout`'d outputs:

```
layout( location = 0 ) out vec4 out_color0;
layout( location = 1 ) out vec4 out_color1;
layout( location = 2 ) out vec4 out_color2;
layout( location = 3 ) out vec4 out_color3;
void main()
{
    out_color0 = vec4( 1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 );
    out_color1 = vec4( 1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 );
    out_color2 = vec4( 1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 );
    out_color3 = vec4( 1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

...or an output array:

```
out vec4 out_color[4];
void main()
{
    out_color[0] = vec4( 1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 );
    out_color[1] = vec4( 1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 );
    out_color[2] = vec4( 1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 );
    out_color[3] = vec4( 1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

Here's the program I'm using for testing, it (tries) to draw a red triangle to all four FBO attachments & then blits the 3rd attachment to the default framebuffer:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* shader, ... )
    {
        const GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, shader );
        while( shader )
        {
            AttachShader( prog, va_arg( args, GLenum ), shader );
            shader = va_arg( args, const char* );
        }
        va_end( args );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        const GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

const char* vert = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 300 es
void main()
{
    const vec2 verts[3] = vec2[3]
    (
        vec2( -0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec2(  0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec2(  0.0,  0.5 )
    );
    gl_Position = vec4( verts[ gl_VertexID ], 0.0, 1.0 );
}
)GLSL";

const char* frag = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
out vec4 out_color;
void main()
{
    out_color = vec4( 1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
)GLSL";

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback( []( int err, const char* desc )
    {
        std::cerr << "GLFW error: " << desc << std::endl;
    } );

    if( !glfwInit() )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_CREATION_API, GLFW_EGL_CONTEXT_API );
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "GLFW", NULL, NULL );
    if( nullptr == window )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    glfwSwapInterval( 1 );
    gladLoadGLES2Loader( (GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress );

    const GLuint prog = Program::Load( vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, NULL );
    glUseProgram( prog );

    // init framebuffer attachments
    std::vector< GLuint > textures( 4, 0 );
    glGenTextures( 4, textures.data() );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < textures.size(); ++ i )
    {
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i] );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr );
    }
    GLuint rbDepth = 0;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbDepth );
    glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbDepth );
    glRenderbufferStorage( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, 32, 32 );

    // init FBO
    GLuint fbo = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers( 1, &fbo );
    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < textures.size(); ++ i )
    {
        glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i], 0 );
    }
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbDepth );
    if( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE != glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER ) )
    {
        std::cerr << "Incomplete framebuffer" << std::endl;
        std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        // render to FBO
        glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo );
        GLenum bufs[] =
        {
            GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 0,
            GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 1,
            GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 2,
            GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 3,
        };
        glDrawBuffers( 4, bufs );
        glViewport( 0, 0, 32, 32 );
        glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.6f, 1.0f, 1.f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );

        // switch back to default framebuffer & clear it with non-black color
        glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
        GLenum defaultBuf = GL_BACK;
        glDrawBuffers( 1, &defaultBuf );
        glClearColor( 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        // blit a color attachment to the default framebuffer
        glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo );
        glReadBuffer( GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 2 );
        glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
        glBlitFramebuffer( 0, 0, 32, 32, 0, 0, 640, 480, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR );

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( NULL );
    glfwDestroyWindow( window );

    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On this Windows 10 machine using a recent-ish [ANGLE](https://github.com/google/angle) build I get the blue clear color but no triangle ("undefined") for the 3rd attachment:

[image: bad output]

The first attachment is fine:

[image: good output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No such functionality exists in the API](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_draw_buffers.txt):

> 3) Should we support broadcast from gl_FragColor to all gl_FragData[x]
>    or should it be synonymous with gl_FragData[0]?
>
> DISCUSSION: With NV_draw_buffers, writing to gl_FragColor writes to all
>    the enabled draw buffers (ie broadcast). In OpenGL ES 3.0 when using
>    ESSL 1.0, gl_FragColor is equivalent to writing a single output to
>    gl_FragData[0] and multiple outputs are not possible. When using ESSL 3.0,
>    only user-defined out variables may be used.
>
> If broadcast is supported, some implementations may have to replace
>    writes to gl_FragColor with replicated writes to all possible gl_FragData
>    locations when this extension is enabled.
>
> RESOLVED: Writes to gl_FragColor are broadcast to all enabled color
>    buffers. ES 3.0 using ESSL 1.0 doesn't support broadcast because
>    ESSL 1.0 was not extended to have multiple color outputs (but that is
>    what this extension adds). **ESSL 3.0 doesn't support the broadcast because
>    it doesn't have the gl_FragColor variable at all, and only has user-
>    defined out variables.** This extension extends ESSL 1.0 to have multiple
>    color outputs. Broadcasting from gl_FragColor to all enabled color
>    buffers is the most consistent with existing draw buffer extensions to
>    date (both NV_draw_buffers and desktop GL).